# Check if a predicate is of standard type in Sesame

Tags: rdf, predicate, sesame, openrdf

Is there any possibility in Sesame to check if a Predicate (URI), is w3c standard predicate(RDFS predicates for example) like RDF.TYPE or is included in RDF vocabulary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just compare the namespace part of the IRI to the vocabulary namespace, like so:

```java
IRI predicate = ... ; // predicate you want to check
switch (predicate.getNamespace()) {
      case RDF.NAMESPACE: 
            // it's an RDF predicate
            break;
      case RDFS.NAMESPACE: 
            // it's an RDFS predicate
            break;
      ... etc
}
```

Of course this won't tell you if the predicate *actually* exists as part of the RDF/RDFS vocabulary - it merely tells you that its namespace part corresponds. So if your predicate is some made-up property, e.g. `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#foobar`, it will also conclude it's part of the RDF namespace: it doesn't verify if the `foobar` property actually exists in that namespace.

Check the [API Javadoc](http://rdf4j.org/doc/4/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/model/vocabulary/RDFS.html) for a complete overview of all property constants in the RDF and RDFS vocabularies.